# How is the Layer Order is decided in leaflet map?

Tags: leaflet

When I use the following code to go through all the layers in a leaflet map,

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
   console.log(layer);
});
```

I just wants what rule is used to create this order. Is it because of the ZIndex of the layer? Or is it because the layer is added in different time? If the layer is added early, it will be in the bottom.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Good question, it seems the [LeafletJS docs](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-layers) don't say anything about the ordering of the layers via `eachLayer`, so...

Looking at the code on github, [L.Map.eachLayer](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/Layer.js#L117) loops through [L.Map._layers](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/map/Map.js#L46) which is an object (not an array).  So technically the layers could come back [in any order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)...

That said, the individual layers are [added](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/Layer.js#L68) to the `_layers` object in the order they are added to the map.  So in all likelihood, `eachLayer` will be iterating over the layers in that same order (whatever order they were added to the map).